# Disable real-time error and warning check in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I find it distracting that Eclipse checks the code for errors and warnings during typing. Is it possible to change this behavior, so that it only checks when I'm done writing a line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you were talking about java code, the checkbox can be found via 'Preferences - Java - Editor' -> 'Report problems as you type'.

```
String tmp =             // no syntax error here
String tmp = ;           // line end -> syntax error
```

For other editors use 'General - Editors - Structured Text Editors'-> 'Report problems as you type'. It's not necessary to deactivate 'build automatically'.

Comment: Perhaps the control has been added under more of the language-specific settings in newer versions of Eclipse because I was able to find it under 'Preferences' >> 'C/C++' >> 'Editor'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to change it to compile after each line. But you can turn automatic compilation off altogether in the menu Project->Build Automatically.