# How to delay Eclipse error warnings

Tags: java, eclipse

I find the error warnings in Eclipse helpful. But the problem is they show up too early when I'm still typing and haven't finished the line of code at hand. This is distracting. How can I delay the error warnings so that they don't show up until I've finished a line and move to the next line?

Comment: I'm not sure you can. besides, how is the IDE to tell whether or not you are finished typing, or are still in the middle of the process?

Comment: @Stultuske Spell checkers don't spell check words when the cursor is at the end of the word because you may have only written half the word. They generally don't check grammar until end of the sentence for the same reason. IDEs could easily just not check lines of code where the cursor still is. This simple concept can even work if expanded to `{}` blocks - wait until I move the cursor out of the current block before checking it.

Answer (score 2):

If you were talking about java code, the checkbox can be found via 'Preferences - Java - Editor' -> 'Report problems as you type'.

```
String tmp =             // no syntax error here
String tmp = ;           // line end -> syntax error
```

For other editors use 'General - Editors - Structured Text Editors'-> 'Report problems as you type'. It's not necessary to deactivate 'build automatically'.

Answer is from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8422753/3651739) by [proko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1086443/proko)

Comment: Thanks. But this will turn off the warnings entirely.

Comment: if you end the statment with ; it will show the errors

Comment: I tried. It didn't. Probably they changed the settings in Eclipse.